# Sort array based on an array - php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I have an array of superheroes named `$heroes`:

```
$heroes=array("Hulk","Spiderman","IronMan");
```

and I have an array of basic powers named `$powers`:

```
$powers=array("Strong","Webs","Machine");
```

I would like to sort the `$heroes` array alphabetically, so that it displays this:

```
$heroes=array("Hulk","IronMan","Spiderman");
```

and with this, I would like the powers to be sorted based on the $heroes array so that it displays this:

```
$powers=array("Strong","Machine","Webs");
```

I would not like to use a two dimensional array - I need them to be in seperate arrays. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, that's what [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is for, little example:

```
array_multisort( $heroes, SORT_ASC|SORT_STRING, $powers);
```

Or just plain (simpler):

```
array_multisort( $heroes, $powers);
```

But it's better to make sort type and sort order explicit.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_multisort($heroes,$powers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array3 = array_combine($array1, $array2);
asort($array3);

$array1 = array_keys($array3);
$array2 = array_values($array3);
```